# Performing a Gaussian fit on many arrays in a matrix in a row and saving the results

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a matrix of data with 1024 columns of 100 values each where I'm trying to perform a Gaussian fit to each column and save the results in a new array. My code is the following:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
import numpy as np

Image1 = fits.open('Image.fits')

Image_data = Image1.data[:,:]

x = np.linspace(-50,50,50)

Gauss_Model = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=1000., mean=0, stddev=1.)

Fitting_Model = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

Fit_Data = Fitting_Model(Gauss_Model, x, Image_data[:,0])
```

This code works just fine and gives a fit to the first column in Image_data, but I want it to perform a fit to all 1024 columns of data in Image_data and save the results in a new array. I tried to use a for-loop but it didn't work. I would very much appreciate some help with how to do this, thanks!

Comment: Can you show your for-loop code?

Comment: At the end it would just be

    for i in range(1023):
        Fit_Data = Fitting_Model(Gauss_Model, x, Image_data[:,i])

but Fit_Data just becomes the result for the last column in this case.

Comment: Well, `Image_data[:, i]` in your example. And that didn't work because?

Comment: I had to edit my comment, but Fit_Data becomes the result for the last column instead of the result for all of them.

Comment: So, store Fit_data in a list, or a dict?

Comment: How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the results in a list:

```
Fit_Data = []
for i in range(0, Image_data.shape[1]):
    Fit_Data.append(Fitting_Model(Gauss_Model, x, Image_data[:, i]))
```

To retrieve fit data results for a specific column, you can call `Fit_Data[32]` for eg